# *Finished* Instagram API works on local server but in deployed it's not working, returns a 404

Tags: reactjs, api, deployment, instagram-api, vercel

**I'm developing an application in React using TypeScript and VITE, my component that calls the API is this**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperProps, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { A11y, Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css'
import 'swiper/css/pagination'
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar'

interface IFeedItem {
  id: string;
  media_type: "CAROUSEL_ALBUM" | "IMAGE" | "VIDEO";
  children: string;
  data: Array<any>;
  is_carousel_item: boolean;
  media_url: string;
  permalink: string;
}
export function Image() {
  const settings: SwiperProps = {
    spaceBetween: 1,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    pagination: {
      clickable: true
    },
    loop: true

  }
  const [feedList, setFeedList] = useState<IFeedItem[]>([]);
  const token = import.meta.env.VITE_INSTA_TOKEN;
  const fields = ["media_url, media_type, permalink,children{media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url}"]
  const url = `https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?access_token=${token}&fields=${fields}`;
  async function getInstaFeed() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url)
    setFeedList(data.data)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getInstaFeed();
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <div className='grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 z-0 cursor-pointer h-auto w-auto transition-all object object-cover object-center'>
        {feedList.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id} >
            {item.media_type === "CAROUSEL_ALBUM" && (
              <Swiper modules={[Navigation, Pagination, A11y]} {...settings} className="z-0">
                {item.children.data.map(child => (
                  <SwiperSlide key={child.id} className="z-0">
                    <a href={item.permalink} target="_blanck">
                      <img src={child.media_url} alt="instagram" />
                    </a>
                  </SwiperSlide>
                ))}
              </Swiper>
            )}
            {item.media_type === "IMAGE" && (
              <img className="" key={item.id} src={item.media_url} />
            )}
            {item.media_type === "VIDEO" && (
              <video controls>
                <source src={item.media_url} />
              </video>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

I'm using the Swiper library to make a carousel, because the instagram API returns information of type CAROUSEL_ALBUM, where there are children that contain the images, so to use it in an interesting way I did it like this.

**When I run the server on my machine in localhost/portfolio everything is ok**
[Image - working in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZcX7.jpg)

**But when I use VERCEL to access /portfolio I get a 404**
[Image - not working in vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9ihE.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, sorry if I was not very clear, actually I was solving this problem until now, I looked in several places, I asked the university students for help. Ultimately it was not an API error, but a VERCEL error in 'seeing' my directories. I had to create a file in the root of my project 'vercel.json' and put it here:

{"rewrites":  [{"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}]}